# I keep losing the values and getting 0's. What's the wrong with my logic?

Tags: c++, sorting, merge, mergesort

Hi everyone I need to write merge sort in C++ using a given header for mergeSort();

I have the partitioning correct but at a point where its merging an array that was merged before it has 0's. For example: If I have [34][21] i get [21, 34] but when this is merged with let's say [8] it gives [0, 0, 8]. I am losing values. Please help me debug it.

---

**Note:** I have some **moveCount** to count data moves and **compCount** to count computations. Please don't get confused with those.

---

```
int * merge(int * left ,int szLeft ,int * right,int szRight, int &compCount, int &moveCount){
    int * newArr = new int [szLeft+szRight];
    cout << "Left: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < szLeft; ++i){
        cout << left[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Right: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < szRight; ++i){
        cout << right[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    int bigArrIndex = 0, rightArrIndex = 0,leftArrIndex = 0;

    while(leftArrIndex < szLeft && rightArrIndex < szRight){
        compCount++;
        if(right[rightArrIndex] <= left[leftArrIndex]){
            newArr[bigArrIndex] = right[rightArrIndex];
            rightArrIndex++;
            compCount++;
        }
        else{
            newArr[bigArrIndex] = left[leftArrIndex];
            leftArrIndex++;
        }
        moveCount++;
        bigArrIndex++;
    }

    //1 more computation done even if the loop is not executed
    compCount++;

    //copy the rest of the stuff if left
    while(rightArrIndex < szRight){
        moveCount++;
        compCount++;
        newArr[bigArrIndex] = right[rightArrIndex];
        rightArrIndex++;
        bigArrIndex++;
    }
    //1 more computation done even if the loop is not executed
    compCount++;

    //copy the rest of the stuff if left
    while(leftArrIndex < szLeft){
        moveCount++;
        compCount++;
        newArr[bigArrIndex] = left[leftArrIndex];
        leftArrIndex++;
        bigArrIndex++;
    }

    //1 more computation done even if the loop is not executed
    compCount++;

    return newArr;
}


void mergeSort( int * arr, int size, int &compCount, int &moveCount){
    //to take the branch or not needs 1 comparison
    compCount++;

    if(size > 1){
        int mid = size/2;
        int * left = new int[mid];
        int * right = new int[size-mid];


        for(int i = 0; i < mid; i++){
            compCount++;
            left[i] = arr[i];
            moveCount++;
        }
        //1 more computation done even if the loop is not executed
        compCount++;

        for(int i = mid; i < size; i++){
            right[i-mid] = arr[i];
            moveCount++;
            compCount++;
        }
        //1 more computation done even if the loop is not executed
        compCount++;

        mergeSort(left,mid,compCount,moveCount);
        mergeSort(right,size-mid,compCount,moveCount);
        int * sortedArr = merge(left,mid,right,size-mid,compCount,moveCount);
        cout << "Done: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            cout << sortedArr[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;

        //delete[] left;
        //delete[] right;

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            arr[i] = sortedArr[size];
            moveCount++;
            compCount++;
        } 
        //1 more computation done even if the loop is not executed
        compCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: *Please help me debug it.* --  Use the debugger that comes with your compiler.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't know how to use gdb. I am using g++ compiler

Comment: Well, now is a good time to learn to use the debugger.  Programming isn't just about writing code, running code, and if there is a problem, go to SO for help.  Learning how to debug code is part and parcel of learning how to write a program.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I got not much time left and ofc I am trying to debug it. LOL. I am not slacking off. But more minds are better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one line. Fix noted in comment:

```
        //delete[] left;
        //delete[] right;

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            arr[i] = sortedArr[i];    // fix from [size] to [i]
            moveCount++;
            compCount++;
        }
```

Comment: in mergeSort, rather than allocate left and right, the code could use arr instead of left, and arr+mid instead of right. Two less allocations. An entry / helper function could do a one time allocation of a temp array the same size as the original array, and pass that as a parameter to mergeSort() which would in turn pass it as a parameter to merge(). In that case, all mergeSort does is create pairs of indices on the stack, and merge does the actual merge and copy back.

Although probably beyond the scope of this class, the copy back can also be eliminated with two mutually recursive versions of mergeSort, one where the merged data ends in in the original array, call this mergeSortO(), one where the merged data ends up in the temp array, call this mergeSortT(). mergeSortO() calls mergeSortT() twice (left and right halves), then calls merge() to merge from temp array to original array. mergeSortT() calls mergeSortO() twice (left and right halves), then calls merge() to merge from original array to temp array, or if size is 1, it copies one element from original to temp array.

Also probably beyond the class, another alternative would be bottom up merge sort, as most libraries such as STL std::stable_sort() use some variation of bottom up merge sort.

Comment: I did what you said but still the same. Actually that was an excellent idea passing the arrays like that so that it increases performance. But there is no performance :(

Comment: @ErinAvllazagaj - are you sure you made the change (sortedArr[i]) and recompiled? I tried this with your example, array[] = {34, 21, 8}, and some other small arrays and it works.

Comment: thanks for the support I will try your suggestions and hopefully get it working

Comment: @ErinAvllazagaj - copy the code posted above, make the one line fix (sortArr[i]), then try it again. It should work. Once it's working, back up the source file before trying to make any improvements.

Comment: thanks a lot mate I can't believe I wrote that stupidity. Thank you for pointing that out. I must have been really tired. That single line was the problem